# receber ajax json POST no php e retornar no sucesso

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

O que estou fazendo de errado?

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#btn1').click(function(){
            var tmp = {"Proc":3236470};
            $.ajax({
              type: 'POST',
              url: 'test.php',
              data: {'rel':tmp},
              success: function(data) {
                $('body').append(data);
                //alert(data);
              }
            });
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="btn1">
        teste
    </button>
</body>
```

test.php

```
<?php
header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate'); 
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8')

$aDados = json_decode($_POST['rel'], true);

echo $aDados["Proc"];
?>
```

ERRO:  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$aDados' (T_VARIABLE)

Comment: Se puder explicar melhor o problema que tem em concreto e, se possível, mostrar código que já tenha feito onde se encontre esse problema. Está demasiado ampla a sua pergunta, veja na [Central de Ajuda Como Perguntar](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: minha dúvida é simples, receber este $_POST no relatorio.php

Comment: Ajax é uma requisição literalmente igual à requisição que um formulário faz ao seu arquivo php, você trabalha o `$_POST` da mesma forma que trabalharia com um formulário. O *success* no ajax representa sucesso ao efetuar a requisição, significa q não expirou o tempo de requisição, que a página requisitada existe e etc.

Comment: ok, eu entendi, uso contantemente $.ajax com .net mvc4, porem, no php estou tendo dificuldades, fiz tudo que informei e q me passaram aqui, mas nada funciona..

Comment: Aprece alguma mensagem de erro no console do chrome ou no firebug(firefox) ?

Comment: Esse último erro, `unexpected '$aDados' (T_VARIABLE)` aconteceu pq faltou um `;` no segundo `header(....)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para receber os dados do ajax basta utilizar o método(POST) e chave correta(rel) como indicado no seu código

```
data: {'rel': tmp},
```

Para transformar o json em um array no php utilize [json_decode()](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.json-decode.php)

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');// para formatar corretamente os acentos

$arr = json_decode($_POST['rel'], true);

echo  '<pre>';
print_r($arr);
```

saida:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Proc] => 3236470
            [Envio] => 08/05/2014
            [Usuário Digitalizador] => CSC TI
            [Tp Doc] => Serviços
            [Unidade] => CSC-TI
        )

)
```

Comment: Obrigado pela atenção Perdeu, mas queria retornar isso em um alert, ou console.log, no success do ajax, pode ajudar?

Comment: Faço o processamento e de um echo na mensagem que vc quer, essa saida de texto será acessível no `sucess` pela variável `data`,

    `success: function(data) {
      alert(data);
    }`

Answer (score 1):

Para o seu PHP (relatorio.php) gerar uma resposta do tipo JSON:

```
<?php
//Alteramos o cabeçalho para não gerar cache do resultado
header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate'); 
//Alteramos o cabeçalho para que o retorno seja do tipo JSON
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8')
//Convertemos o array em um objecto json
echo json_encode(array('erro' => '0','msg' => 'Executado com sucesso'));
?>
```

É importante que o header seja chamado antes de qualquer saída, caso contrário será retornado um "warning", para entender, experimente colocar um ***echo('teste');*** antes do header.

No seu php (relatorio.php), para trabalhar com o array enviado na requisição AJAX, basta fazer o seguinte:

```
<?php
header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate'); 
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8')

$aDados = json_decode($_POST['rel'], true);
$nProc = $aDados["Proc"];

echo json_encode(array("erro" => "0", "proc" => $nProc));
?>
```

Repare que utilizamos um array associativo, ou seja, no lugar de utilizar números como índice, utilizamos nomes, no exemplo acima, "erro" e "proc". Esse nomes estarão disponíveis na função que é executada no parâmetro "success" da sua chamada AJAX.

Para trabalhar com o json que será retornado, altere a função que é executada no parâmetro "success":

```
$('#btn').click(function(){  
    var tmp = {"Proc":3236470,"Envio":"08/05/2014","Usuário Digitalizador":"CSC TI","Tp Doc":"Serviços","Unidade":"CSC-TI"};
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'relatorio.php',
      data: {rel:tmp},
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data) {
        //$('body').append(data);
        alert("O processo número "+data["proc"]+" foi enviado com sucesso");
     }
 });
```

});

Comment: Felipe, fiz como informou, porem continua sem retornar nada, nem alert nem console.log.. meu ajax está correto?

Comment: @Jhonatan eu não sei se da forma como foi feito funciona, altere a sua variável tmp, tente assim: var tmp  = {"Proc":3236470,"Envio":"08/05/2014","Usuário Digitalizador":"CSC TI","Tp Doc":"Serviços","Unidade":"CSC-TI"};  apenas retirei o []

Answer (score 0):

Camarada, rodei seu código aqui e com as tags de header realmente não tava funcionando. Quando as removi passou a dar um errinho pois vc estava passando json direto e usando json_decode, aconte que a função json_decode espera uma string. Então você pode passar como string e usar json_decode no php ou passar como json e não usar json_decode no php.

**Segue código funcionando** :

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $('#btn1').click(function()
        {
            var tmp = {"Proc":3236470};
            //var tmp = '{"Proc":3236470}'; // se usar json_decode, tem que passar como string

            $.ajax({
              type: 'POST',
              url: 'test.php',
              data: {
                  'rel':tmp,
              },
              success: function(data) {
                $('body').append(data);
                // alert(data);
              }
            });
        });

    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="btn1">
        teste
    </button>
</body>
<html>
```

Página test.php:

```
<?php

//$aDados = json_decode($_POST['rel'], true);

$aDados = $_POST['rel'];    //se for passar como json direto, não usar json_decode

var_dump($aDados);
```

Comment: ele so mostra o data no alert, na pagina php fica null